# What does |= mean in this instance

Tags: c#

What does the line of code below mean in this instance ?

```
lPutMsgOptions.Options |= MQC.MQPMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING + MQC.MQPMO_SET_IDENTITY_CONTEXT ;
```

Comment: Your question title has `!=`, but your code has `|=`. They don't mean the same thing.

Comment: Did you read [the docs about `|=`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f1zzaw.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

| is a bitwise OR operator. The code could also be written as follows:

```
lPutMsgOptions.Options = lPutMsgOptions.Options | (MQC.MQPMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING + MQC.MQPMO_SET_IDENTITY_CONTEXT) ;
```

It is used to set the two binary enum flags MQPMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING and MQPMO_SET_IDENTITY_CONTEXT.

You could for example define a similar enumeration as follows:

```
enum Days { Sat=1, Sun=2, Mon=4, Tue=8, Wed=16, Thu=32, Fri=64 };
```

Using the binary OR operator (|) you can combine the different days of the week.

Comment: why would you use it in this context ?

Answer (score 1):

It performs a bitwise OR operation.

It is shorthand for:

```
lPutMsgOptions.Options = lPutMsgOptions.Options | MQC.MQPMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING + MQC.MQPMO_SET_IDENTITY_CONTEXT ;
```